# What will be the time complexity of this code?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I've this code :

```
int arr [];
QuickSort.(arr); // O(log n)
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length() - 1; i++) {
    print(i); // O(n)
}
```

What is the time complexity of this? Is it `O(n * log n)` or `O(n + log n)`?

Comment: What is your guess? And why?

Comment: It should be `O(n + log n)`. As they are not nested.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. But quicksort is not `O(log n)`

Comment: But worst time complexity of QuickSort is `O(log n)`.

Comment: No sorry, worst case is `O(n^2)`

Comment: Yes. But many places I've seen the complexity is `O(n * log n)`.

Comment: There are no sort algorithms that can be O(log n): all values need to be visited, so it is just not possible to get sublinear complexity. Average is O(nlogn), worst case for QuickSort is O(n²).

Comment: `O(n*log n + n)` but you can ignore n. So `O(n * log n)`. `Quicksort()` is dominant here

Answer (score 0):

```
O(log n) + O(n) =
O(n + log n) = 
O(n)
```

In the complexity analysis, you keep the biggest factor only. As `n > log n`, `log n` disappears because its growth is negligible when compared to `n`'s when `n` goes to infinity.

On the other hand, the quicksort algorithm is an `O(n²)` algorithm, so I guess the real complexity should be:

```
O(n²) + O(n) =
O(n² + n) = 
O(n²)
```

Where `n` is the size of the array.